# Getting the logged in username in ASP.NET MVC3 intranet application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication, intranet

I am working on a MVC 3 intranet application ( windows authentication ). The application must display the profile page of the user once a user logs in. In order to do that the username of the logged in user must be passed in as a route parameter in the following route in Global.asax.cs.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Initial",
    "{controller}/{action}/{emailAlias}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", userId = **<USERNAME>**}
);
```

Here, for the  I've used some alternatives.

1. At first I used `Environment.Username`. Which works well in development. But not after publishing. Because then `Environment.Username` yields the name of the applications pool which the app runs in. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx).
2. `Controller.User.Identity.Name` is used to get the desired username in controllers, works well in pre and post publishing. But it cannot be used in the context of Global.asax.cs.
3. `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` yields null reference.
4. `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` works kind of same as `Environment.Username`

I'm sure it's easy to figure out that I'm a noob by now. Maybe I've missed something obvious. If so please point that out or please tell me of a simple solution thanks in advance.

Comment: So when I change userId to my coworker's username his profile will show up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The global.asax code is supposed to be run at application startup (and shutdown) and you don't have any session or a user at that time (hence the name **global**). Why do you need the username in the route? You should just use `User.Identity.Name` in the controllers' code to identify the user instead of relying in getting it as a parameter.